# Display an array of number in diferent columns vertically

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'd like to know if it's possible to do the following.
I have an array of numbers that looks like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zjq5R.jpg

But the way I want it displayed is as follows:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/dCpUM.jpg

That is, I want the numbers to go down and come back up in another column when you reach a particular row number, like row 10. When you reach row 10 you keep showing the numbers in another column, and so on.

So, is there a way to do this with the ngFor Angular directive or some other method?

Thank you

UPDATE:

My array looks like this:

```
numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
```

And the HTML code to display the array is this:

```
<div class="grid-container">
    <p class="grid-item" *ngFor="let number of numbers">{{ number }}</p>
</div>
```

To display the array like the images above I use grid, css code here:

```
.grid-example {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: auto auto auto auto;
}

.grid-item {
    padding: 10px 10px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: azure;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

With this config/code, that's what I see on the app:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/u2dEr.jpg

So, is there any way to display this array like I said before or I must make it a bidimensional array before display it?

Simplified code:

```js
numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
```

```css
.grid-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: auto auto auto auto;
}

.grid-item {
    padding: 10px 10px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: azure;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
    <p class="grid-item">1</p>
    <p class="grid-item">2</p>
    <p class="grid-item">3</p>
    <p class="grid-item">4</p>
    <p class="grid-item">5</p>
    <p class="grid-item">6</p>
    <p class="grid-item">7</p>
    <p class="grid-item">8</p>
    <p class="grid-item">9</p>
    <p class="grid-item">10</p>
</div>
```

Comment: can you please detail a bit your question? will it always be this particular array? by displaying, you referring to html? and can you show the code you have so far?

Answer (score 0):

You can rearrange your array numbers using this method then you can just render the array normally.

```js
const row = 10
const column = 5
let arr = []
for (let i = 0; i < row; i++) {
  for (let j = 0; j < column; j++) {
    arr.push((j * row) + i + 1)
  }
}
console.log(arr)
```

Comment: Okey, and what happends if I want to rearrange an arrays of objects, can I use this way? For example, I want to display the array in 10 columns and 10 rows, and I have 200 objects inside the array, how can I rearrange it?